# Printing the result linked list in correct order

Tags: c, linked-list

I am writing a program which add 2 given polynomials into a third one using linked lists but the result linked list is in reverse order and I cant get my head around it

Inputs:
(10x7 + 5x4 + 3x2 + 5) + (3x8 + 3x4 + 3x -6)

result:
-1x0 + 3x + 3x2 + 8x4 + 10x7 + 3x8

I want it:
3x8 + 10x7 + 8x4 + 3x2 +3x -1x0

those are the functions:

```
typedef struct term
{
    int coef;
    int exp;
    struct term *next;
} term;
        
void Push2(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
    struct term *newNode = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
    if (coef == 0)
        return;
            
    newNode->coef = coef;
    newNode->exp = exp;
    newNode->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}

term *addPolynomials2(term *h1, term *h2)
{
    term *current1 = h1;
    term *current2 = h2;
        
    term *new = NULL;
    while (current1 && current2)
    {
        if (current1->exp == current2->exp)
        {
            Push2(&new, (current1->coef + current2->coef), current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
        else if (current1->exp > current2->exp)
        
        {
            Push2(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
        }
        
        else
        {
            Push2(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
            current2 = current2->next;
        }
    }

    while (current1)
    {
        Push2(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
        current1 = current1->next;
    }

    while (current2)
    {
        Push2(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    return new;
}

void printTerm(term head)
{
    printf("%dx%d ", head.coef, head.exp);
}

void printPolynomial(term *head)
{
    if (head == 0)
        return;
            
    printTerm(*head);
    printPolynomial(head->next);
}

void addPolynomialsTest2()
{
    term *head1 = NULL;
    term *head2 = NULL;
    term *new;
    int a[] = {10, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 5};
    
    int b[] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    for (int i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Push2(&head1, a[i], b[i]);
    }
    
    int c[] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    int d[] = {3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, -6};
    for (int i = sizeof(d) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
    
        Push2(&head2, d[i], c[i]);
    }
    printf("F(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Q(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("F(x) + Q(X)= ");
    new = addPolynomials2(head1, head2);
    printPolynomial(new);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `Push2` puts the new element at the front. So when you push all the terms, the last one you push will be at the front of the list, and it will be in reverse order. Change `Push2()` to add the new element at the end if you want them to stay in order.

Comment: Or print the list in reverse order. That's easy to do with recursion.

Comment: I tried printing it in reverse and it still didnt give the correct output

Comment: How can that be? If the current output is just in the reverse order, reversing it should produce the correct order.

Comment: @Barmar 3x4 != 8x4

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the `addPolynomials()` function, not with printing.

Comment: I cant see a problem in it

Comment: Why do you want `3x4`? You have `5x4` in the first input and `3x4` in the second. When you add them you get `8x4`.

Comment: ohh sorry thats a typing error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Push2` always pushes to the *front* (i.e. head) of the list.

When combining/adding, you need a push that appends to the *tail* of the list.

Also, I *think* you want the sum to have `8x4` and *not* `3x4` as you say (i.e. your program is correct, except the order is reversed) because each input polynomial has an `x4` term.

Also, your print polynomial function doesn't need to be recursive.

And, don't cast the result of `malloc`

---

Here's a refactored version with some debug prints.  I created a second push function for appending. Ignore the `TERM` [macro]--it was an incomplete attempt at clarity before I found the real issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct term {
    int coef;
    int exp;
    struct term *next;
} term;

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

typedef void (*pushfnc_p)(term **headRef, int coef, int exp);

void
Push2(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
    term *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

    if (coef == 0)
        return;

    newNode->coef = coef;
    newNode->exp = exp;
    newNode->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}

void
Push2_tail(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
    term *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    term *head = *headRef;

    if (coef == 0)
        return;

    term *prev = NULL;
    for (struct term *cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    newNode->coef = coef;
    newNode->exp = exp;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newNode;
    else
        head = newNode;

    *headRef = head;
}

term *
addPolynomials2(term *h1, term *h2)
{
    term *current1 = h1;
    term *current2 = h2;
#if 0
    pushfnc_p push = Push2;
#else
    pushfnc_p push = Push2_tail;
#endif

    term *new = NULL;

    while (current1 && current2) {
        dbgprt("add: DUAL current1=%dX%d current2=%dX%d\n",
            current1->coef,current1->exp,
            current2->coef,current2->exp);

        if (current1->exp == current2->exp) {
            dbgprt("add: SAME\n");
            push(&new, (current1->coef + current2->coef), current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
            current2 = current2->next;
            continue;
        }

        if (current1->exp > current2->exp) {
            dbgprt("add: CURR1\n");
            push(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
            continue;
        }

        dbgprt("add: CURR2\n");
        push(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    while (current1) {
        dbgprt("add: POST1 current1=%dX%d\n",
            current1->coef,current1->exp);
        push(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
        current1 = current1->next;
    }

    while (current2) {
        dbgprt("add: POST2 current2=%dX%d\n",
            current2->coef,current2->exp);
        push(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    return new;
}

void
printTerm(term *head)
{
    printf("%dx%d ", head->coef, head->exp);
}

void
printPolynomial(term *head)
{

    for (;  head != NULL;  head = head->next)
        printTerm(head);
}

#define TERM(_coef,_exp) \
    { .coef = _coef, .exp = _exp },

void
addPolynomialsTest2(void)
{
    term *head1 = NULL;
    term *head2 = NULL;
    term *new;

#if 1
    int a[] = { 10, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 5 };
    int b[] = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    for (int i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Push2(&head1, a[i], b[i]);
    }

    int c[] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int d[] = { 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, -6 };
    for (int i = sizeof(d) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Push2(&head2, d[i], c[i]);
    }
#else
    term a[] = {
        TERM(10,7)
        TERM(0,6)
        TERM(0,5)
        TERM(5,4)
        TERM(0,3)
        TERM(3,2)
        TERM(0,5)
    };
    for (int i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(term) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        term *t = &a[i];
        Push2(&head1,t->coef,t->exp);
    }
#endif

    printf("F(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Q(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("F(x) + Q(X)= ");
    new = addPolynomials2(head1, head2);
    printPolynomial(new);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    addPolynomialsTest2();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
F(x)= 3x8 3x4 3x1 -6x0
Q(x)= 10x7 5x4 3x2 5x0
F(x) + Q(X)= 3x8 10x7 8x4 3x2 3x1 -1x0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I tried doing it without inserting at the end by printing the result in reverse but the output was even weirder any idea why?

Not completely sure. Sounds like two wrongs making a right ... See below.

When *creating* the polynomials, your code using push-to-front *does* work, but, IMO, it's a bit more complex because you have to loop through the arrays in reverse order.

However, the add function *does* need push-to-tail. With push-to-front, the add will fail. So, trying to print in reverse order to "compensate" for the incorrect add function may not be a valid fix.

So, with the original code, you had the two input polynomials in high-to-low order [as we'd want], but the *output* polynomial had its order *reversed*.

So, if you tried to add the output to something else (e.g. one of the inputs again), it would *break*.

So, compensating by reverse printing does *not* fix the problem. It masks it for printing only.

The push-to-front isn't really needed. I got the `TERM` macro working. It uses push-to-tail and traverses the array from 0 to N [simpler to understand].

So, this is, IMO, a bit cleaner:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct term {
    int coef;
    int exp;
    struct term *next;
} term;

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif

typedef void (*pushfnc_p)(term **headRef, int coef, int exp);

void
Push2(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
    term *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));

    if (coef == 0)
        return;

    newNode->coef = coef;
    newNode->exp = exp;
    newNode->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = newNode;
}

void
Push2_tail(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
    term *newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    term *head = *headRef;

    if (coef == 0)
        return;

    term *prev = NULL;
    for (struct term *cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    newNode->coef = coef;
    newNode->exp = exp;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newNode;
    else
        head = newNode;

    *headRef = head;
}

term *
addPolynomials2(term *h1, term *h2)
{
    term *current1 = h1;
    term *current2 = h2;
#if 0
    pushfnc_p push = Push2;
#else
    pushfnc_p push = Push2_tail;
#endif

    term *new = NULL;

    while (current1 && current2) {
        dbgprt("add: DUAL current1=%dX%d current2=%dX%d\n",
            current1->coef,current1->exp,
            current2->coef,current2->exp);

        if (current1->exp == current2->exp) {
            dbgprt("add: SAME\n");
            push(&new, (current1->coef + current2->coef), current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
            current2 = current2->next;
            continue;
        }

        if (current1->exp > current2->exp) {
            dbgprt("add: CURR1\n");
            push(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
            current1 = current1->next;
            continue;
        }

        dbgprt("add: CURR2\n");
        push(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    while (current1) {
        dbgprt("add: POST1 current1=%dX%d\n",
            current1->coef,current1->exp);
        push(&new, current1->coef, current1->exp);
        current1 = current1->next;
    }

    while (current2) {
        dbgprt("add: POST2 current2=%dX%d\n",
            current2->coef,current2->exp);
        push(&new, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }

    return new;
}

void
printTerm(term *head)
{
    printf("%dx%d ", head->coef, head->exp);
}

void
printPolynomial(term *head)
{

    for (;  head != NULL;  head = head->next)
        printTerm(head);
}

#define TERM(_coef,_exp) \
    { .coef = _coef, .exp = _exp },

void
addPolynomialsTest2(void)
{
    term *head1 = NULL;
    term *head2 = NULL;
    term *new;

#if 0
    int a[] = { 10, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 5 };
    int b[] = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    for (int i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Push2(&head1, a[i], b[i]);
    }

    int c[] = { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int d[] = { 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, -6 };
    for (int i = sizeof(d) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Push2(&head2, d[i], c[i]);
    }
#else
    term ab[] = {
        TERM(10,7)
        TERM(0,6)
        TERM(0,5)
        TERM(5,4)
        TERM(0,3)
        TERM(3,2)
        TERM(0,5)
    };
    for (int i = 0;  i < sizeof(ab) / sizeof(term); ++i) {
        term *t = &ab[i];
        Push2_tail(&head1,t->coef,t->exp);
    }

    term cd[] = {
        TERM(3,8)
        TERM(0,7)
        TERM(0,6)
        TERM(0,5)
        TERM(3,4)
        TERM(0,3)
        TERM(0,2)
        TERM(3,1)
        TERM(-6,0)
    };
    for (int i = 0;  i < sizeof(cd) / sizeof(term); ++i) {
        term *t = &cd[i];
        Push2_tail(&head2,t->coef,t->exp);
    }
#endif

    printf("F(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head2);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Q(x)= ");
    printPolynomial(head1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("F(x) + Q(X)= ");
    new = addPolynomials2(head1, head2);
    printPolynomial(new);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
}

int
main(void)
{
    addPolynomialsTest2();
    return 0;
}
```

---

It's a moot point because constructing the output in reverse order is incorrect (i.e. do *not* do this).

But, now, I understand why you wanted a *recursive* function to print the polynomial.

To print in *reverse* order, I *think* the function would have to print the *current* term *after* recursively calling itself. I've not thought this out [or tested it]:

```
void
printTerm(term *head)
{
    printf("%dx%d ", head->coef, head->exp);
}

void
printPolynomial(term *head)
{

    if (head == 0)
        return;

#if 0
    printTerm(head);
    printPolynomial(head->next);
#else
    printPolynomial(head->next);
    printTerm(head);
#endif
}
```

This *might* fix the print of the result polynomial.

**But**, doing this would *break* the printing of the two *input* polynomials.

Comment: Thank you
I tried doing it without inserting at the end by printing the result in reverse but the output was even weirder
any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

```
void Reverse(term *Node)
{
if(Node== NULL) return;

Reverse(Node->next);
printTerm(*Node);
}
```

**And call Reverse(New) instead of PrintPolynomial(New)**

Output: F(x) + Q(X)= 3x8 10x7 8x4 3x2 3x1 -1x0

**Full solution:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct term
{
int coef;
int exp;
struct term *next;

} term;


void Push2(term **headRef, int coef, int exp)
{
struct term *NewNode = (term *)malloc(sizeof(term));
if (coef == 0)
    return;

NewNode->coef = coef;
NewNode->exp = exp;
NewNode->next = *headRef;
*headRef = NewNode;
}

term *addPolynomials2(term *h1, term *h2)
{
term *current1 = h1;
term *current2 = h2;

term *New = NULL;
while (current1 && current2)

{
    if (current1->exp == current2->exp)
    {
        Push2(&New, (current1->coef + current2->coef), current1->exp);
        current1 = current1->next;
        current2 = current2->next;
    }
    else if (current1->exp > current2->exp)

    {
        Push2(&New, current1->coef, current1->exp);
        current1 = current1->next;
    }

    else
    {
        Push2(&New, current2->coef, current2->exp);
        current2 = current2->next;
    }
}
while (current1)
{
    Push2(&New, current1->coef, current1->exp);
    current1 = current1->next;
}
while (current2)
{
    Push2(&New, current2->coef, current2->exp);
    current2 = current2->next;
}
return New;
}

void printTerm(term head)
{
 printf("%dx%d ", head.coef, head.exp);
}

void Reverse(term *Node)
{
if(Node== NULL)
    return;
Reverse(Node->next);
printTerm(*Node);
}

void printPolynomial(term *head)
{
if (head == 0)
    return;

printTerm(*head);
printPolynomial(head->next);
 }
void addPolynomialsTest2()
{
term *head1 = NULL;
term *head2 = NULL;
term *New;
int a[] = {10, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0, 5};

int b[] = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
for (int i = sizeof(a) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{

    Push2(&head1, a[i], b[i]);
}

int c[] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
int d[] = {3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, -6};
for (int i = sizeof(d) / sizeof(int) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{

    Push2(&head2, d[i], c[i]);
}
printf("F(x)= ");
printPolynomial(head2);
printf("\n");
printf("Q(x)= ");
printPolynomial(head1);
printf("\n");
printf("F(x) + Q(X)= ");
New = addPolynomials2(head1, head2);

while(New!= NULL)
{
    printTerm(*New);
    New = New->next;
}
Reverse(New);
printf("\n");
printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
addPolynomialsTest2();
}
```

Comment: I approached this solution but no success

Comment: Added full code, please check @mrreaper72