# Empty Linked List condition is true - C language

Tags: c, data-structures, polynomial-math

Im creating a program in C using structures and pointers. I have to add two polynomials together to one simplified one. The problem that I'm having is, the IsEmpty Function to test whether a linked list is empty returns true if L is empty and then prints "empty list". I am not sure why my linked list is empty after putting together my addPolynomial function. This function is located in the list.c file. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Header file:

```
#ifndef _List_H
#define _List_H

 struct Node;  //OK
 typedef struct Node *PtrToNode; //OK
 typedef PtrToNode List; //OK
 typedef PtrToNode Position; //OK

 List MakeEmpty( List L ); //OK
 int IsEmpty( List L );
 int IsLast( Position P, List L );
 List addPolynomial(List L1, List L2);
 Position FindPrevious( int e, List L );
 void Insert( int c, int e, List L );
 void DeleteList( List L );
 Position Header( List L );
 Position First( List L );
 Position Advance( Position P ); 
 int RetrieveCoefficient( Position P ); //OK
 int RetrieveExponent( Position P ); //OK
#endif    /* _List_H */
```

Print/test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

void PrintList( const List L ){
Position P = Header( L );
if( IsEmpty( L ) ) printf( "Empty list\n" );
else{
    do{
        P = Advance( P );
        if(RetrieveCoefficient( P )>0){
            printf( "%+dx^%d ", RetrieveCoefficient( P ), RetrieveExponent( P ));
        }
        else{
            printf( "%dx^%d ", RetrieveCoefficient( P ), RetrieveExponent( P ));
        }
    } while( !IsLast( P, L ) );
    printf( "\n" );
}
}

main(){
List L1,L2,L3;
Position P1,P2;

L1 = MakeEmpty( NULL );
P1 = Header( L1 );
L2 = MakeEmpty( NULL );
P2 = Header( L2 );
L3 = MakeEmpty( NULL );

Insert(3,5,L1);
Insert(2,3,L1);
Insert(-7,8,L1);
Insert(4,9,L1);
Insert(-9,1,L2);
printf("Polynomial 1:\n");
PrintList( L1 );

Insert(4,7,L2);
Insert(5,6,L2);
Insert(-4,3,L2);
Insert(-3,5,L2);
printf("Polynomial 2:\n");
PrintList( L2 );

L3 = addPolynomial(L1,L2);
printf("Polynomial 3:\n");
PrintList( L3 );

DeleteList( L1 );
DeleteList( L2 );
DeleteList( L3 );
return 0;
}
```

list.c file:

```
#include "list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fatal.h"

/* Figure 3.23 Type declaration for linked list implementation of Polynomial ADT */
struct Node{
int Coefficient;
int Exponent;
PtrToNode Next;
};

List MakeEmpty( List L ){
if( L != NULL ) DeleteList( L );
L = (List) malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ); 
if( L == NULL ) FatalError( "Out of memory!" );
L->Next = NULL;
return L;
}

/* Figure 3.8 Function to test whether a linked list is empty */
/* Return true if L is empty */
int IsEmpty( List L ){return L->Next == NULL;}

/* Figure 3.9 Function to test whether current position is the last in a linked list */
/* Return true if P is the last position in list L */
/* Parameter L is unused in this implementation */
int IsLast( Position P, List L ){
return P->Next == NULL;
}
/* END */

List addPolynomial(List L1, List L2){
List L; //Result of L1+L2
Position P,P1,P2;
L = MakeEmpty( NULL );
P = Header( L );
P1 = First(L1);
P2 = First(L2);

// While loops to be used

while (P1->Next && P2->Next)
{
    //move pointer and leave 1st as is if exponent is greater than 2nd poly
    if (P1->Exponent > P2->Exponent){

        P->Exponent = P1->Exponent;
        P->Coefficient = P1->Coefficient;
        P1 = P1->Next;
    }
    //if exponent in 2nd is larger then store L2 and move pointer
    else if (P1->Exponent < P2->Exponent){

        P->Exponent = P2->Exponent;
        P->Coefficient = P2->Coefficient;
        P2 = P2->Next;
    }
    //if both are the same then they're added together
    else{

        P->Exponent = P1->Exponent;
        P->Coefficient = P1->Coefficient + P2->Coefficient;         
        P1 = P1->Next;
        P2 = P2->Next;
    }
    
    P->Next = /*(struct Node *)*/malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    P = P->Next;
    P->Next = NULL;
    
}
while (P1->Next || P2->Next)
{
    if (P1->Next) {

        P->Exponent = P1->Exponent;
        P->Coefficient = P1->Coefficient;
        P1 = P1->Next;
    }

    if (P2->Next) {

        P->Exponent = P2->Exponent;
        P->Coefficient = P2->Coefficient;
        P2 = P2->Next;
    }

    P->Next = /*(struct Node *)*/malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    P = P->Next;
    P->Next = NULL;

}
L = P;
return L;
}

/* Figure 3.13 Insertion routine for linked lists */
/* Insert (after legal position P) */
/* Header implementation assumed */
/* Parameter L is unused in this implementation */
void Insert( int c, int e, List L){
    Position TmpCell;
    Position P = FindPrevious( e, L );

/* 1*/  TmpCell = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ); //(Position)
/* 2*/  if( TmpCell == NULL ) FatalError( "Out of space!!!" );
/* 3*/  TmpCell->Coefficient = c;
/* 4*/  TmpCell->Exponent = e;
/* 5*/  TmpCell->Next = P->Next;
/* 6*/  P->Next = TmpCell;
}

/* Figure 3.12 FindPrevious - the Find routine for use with Delete */
/* If X is not found, then Next field of returned value is NULL */
/* Assumes a header */
Position FindPrevious( int e, List L ){
    Position P;
/* 1*/  P = L;
/* 2*/  while (P->Next != NULL && P->Next->Exponent != e)
/* 3*/  P = P->Next;
/* 4*/  return P;
}

/* Figure 3.15 Correct way to delete a list */
/* Correct DeleteList algorithm */
void DeleteList( List L ){
    Position P, Tmp;
/* 1*/  P = L->Next;  /* Header assumed */
/* 2*/  L->Next = NULL;
/* 3*/  while( P != NULL ){
/* 4*/      Tmp = P->Next;
/* 5*/      free( P );
/* 6*/      P = Tmp;
    }
}

Position Header( List L ){  return L;}
Position First( List L ){   return L->Next;}
Position Advance( Position P ){ return P->Next;}
int RetrieveCoefficient( Position P ){  return P->Coefficient;}
int RetrieveExponent( Position P ){ return P->Exponent;}
```

fatal.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Error( Str )        FatalError( Str )
#define FatalError( Str )   fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", Str ), exit( 1 )
```

output to terminal:

Polynomial 1:
+3x^5 +2x^3 -7x^8 +4x^9

Polynomial 2:
-9x^1 +4x^7 +5x^6 -4x^3 -3x^5

Polynomial 3:
Empty list

Comment: Please reduce this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not just for our sake but even more for your own debugging. For example, remove everything and just create an empty list, then call the isEmpty function. If that works then insert one item and call isEmpty. And so on until you hit the problem.

Comment: One things for sure. The `add` function assumes that the polynomials are sorted by exponent, but the output clearly shows that they are not. So I'd work on that first.

Comment: `List MakeEmpty( List L )` This makes no sense whatsoever. Why do you need a list to make an empty list? An empty list can be made out of nothing. And why does your empty list has a node? A node contains data. An empty list does not contain any data. You can ignore data in the first node of the list, but this is just a recipe for confusion. It is probably a better idea to represent the empty list simply with a null pointer.

Comment: One other thing, if your C book tells you to use `main()` rather than `int main()`, then you should be aware that it is a couple of decades out of date. You may want to read something less ancient.

Comment: Your implementation seem overly complex to me. See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912968/printing-the-result-linked-list-in-correct-order/65913460#65913460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to delete the line `L = P;` at the end of the function `addPolynomial`, then it will work.